# Why does StandardOpenOption.CREATE not work on SMB via Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, nio, samba

I have a Windows file server which is mounted to an Ubuntu server at `/mnt/DrawingsPB`. The mount point is using the SMB protocol to manage files on the Windows server.

I am trying to create a file and overwrite it if it already exists:

```
private Path drawingsTargetDirectory = Paths.get("/mnt/DrawingsPB/Test");

public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    Path directory = drawingsTargetDirectory.resolve("TestDir");
    Files.createDirectories(directory);
    Path path = directory.resolve("TestFile.txt");
    return Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
}
```

This is throwing an [`AccessDeniedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html):

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /mnt/DrawingsPB/Test/TestDir/TestFile.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) [rt.jar:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) [rt.jar:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) [rt.jar:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214) [rt.jar:1.8.0_382]
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434) [rt.jar:1.8.0_382]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216) [rt.jar:1.8.0_382]
    at com.company.router.drawing.impl.FileSystemStreamProvider.lambda$4(FileSystemStreamProvider.java:75) [classes:]
    ... 50 more
```

However, if I do a manual check-and-delete and change `CREATE` to `CREATE_NEW`, it does not fail:

```
public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    Path directory = drawingsTargetDirectory.resolve("TestDir");
    Files.createDirectories(directory);
    Path path = directory.resolve("TestFile.txt");
    if (Files.exists(path))
        Files.delete(path); // Works
    return Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE); // Works
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Java using the nio implementation for Unix file systems may be confused by the SMB mount. Do you have the same issue with a pure native path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

The two operations you are comparing are not equivalent.  Although the details differ between Windows and Linux, modifying the contents of a file, including truncating it to length zero, is a different operation, requiring different permissions, than is deleting the same file:

- In Unix, truncating an existing file requires **write** permission *on the file*, whereas deleting it from a directory requires **write** permission *on the directory*.
- In Windows / NTFS, you need the **Write Data** permission on a file to modify that file's content, including truncating it, but you need either either **Delete** permission on the file *or* **Delete Subfolders and Files** on its directory to delete it.

Since you are denied access to truncate the file, you must not have had **write** / **Write Data** on the file.  Since you were able to delete it, you most likely had **write** / **Delete Subfolders and Files** on the directory, but it is also possible that you had **Delete** (but not **Write Data**) on the file.  The distinction between these will not be reflected in the permissions shown on the Linux side, if even it does any permissions mapping at all.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you think `CREATE_NEW` vs `CREATE` require different permissions as well? I just updated my question.

Comment: @CardinalSystem both of those require **write** / **Create Files** on the folder.  With `CREATE` and a file that already exists, you will also need appropriate permissions on the existing file, in this case **write** / **Write Data**.  If the file does not already exist, however, then `CREATE` should not require any permissions that `CREATE_NEW` does not also require.